# Bounding-Box in requests on overpass-turbo

Tags: openstreetmap

On the overpass-turbo-page ( see http://overpass-turbo.eu/ ) i have tried to run several requests

see the following:

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,"name","addr:postcode","addr:city","addr:street","addr:housenumber","website"," contact:email=*")][timeout:300];
area[bbox="1.200,46.373,19.000,49.017"]->.a;
( node(area.a)[amenity=kindergarten];
  way(area.a)[amenity=kindergarten];
  rel(area.a)[amenity=kindergarten];);
out;
```

the above does not work

the one below does!

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,"name","addr:postcode","addr:city","addr:street","addr:housenumber","website"," contact:email=*")][timeout:300];
area[name="Bayern"]->.a;
( node(area.a)[amenity=kindergarten];
  way(area.a)[amenity=kindergarten];
  rel(area.a)[amenity=kindergarten];);
out;
```

the request below spits out a number of data

well - i do not know why the one with the boundingbox does not work?

in the example with the bounding box i have entered a example from Austria

i took the bounding box from Austria:  see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187402/working-out-the-bounding-box-of-a-coutnry

1.200   46.373   19.000   49.017 
 1.200,46.373,19.000,49.017

why does it not work?

Answer (score 5):

There is an error in your bounding box. `1.200` is clearly wrong (i.e. far away from Austria). Try this bounding box for Austria instead: `46.3722761,9.5307487,49.0205264,17.160776`

Also queries by bounding box work differently. See the [Overpass API language guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#By_exact_name_and_rough_location) for examples.

Try [this query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/laU):

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,"name","addr:postcode","addr:city","addr:street","addr:housenumber","website"," contact:email=*")][timeout:300];
(
node[amenity=kindergarten](46.3722761,9.5307487,49.0205264,17.160776);
way[amenity=kindergarten](46.3722761,9.5307487,49.0205264,17.160776);
relation[amenity=kindergarten](46.3722761,9.5307487,49.0205264,17.160776);
);
out;
```